# How to include php pages in same or different folders?

Tags: php, include, include-path

How can I include the PHP pages if they are in same or different folders without writing full path?

Comment: `./` for same, `../` for parent folder

Comment: I already try this but its not working

Comment: Then please [edit] your question and paste your code that doesn't work along with your folder structure and the errors you get

Comment: Please Refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's the same folder:

```php
include 'filename.php';
```

If it's a parent folder;

```php
include '../filename.php`
```

if it's a folder with the same parent:

```php
include '../foldername/filename.php;`
```